# How to force a monospaced font to render in Facebook?

Tags: css, facebook, render, fonts, monospace

I made a program that generates ASCII art from an image. I want users to be able to copy and paste that ASCII art to their wall and have it display properly.

Problem:

Facebook doesn't use a monospace font.

Does anyone have any ideas on a workaround?

Comment: Not programming related. Belongs on the new Web Apps StackExchange: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This isn't webapp related and programming related.

Answer (score 5):

.

But it must be done one line at a time unfortunately. But it is unicode so you can prepare it first in a text editor and copy/paste into facebook.

Comment: who what? is this a thing?

Comment: Evidently, the website is no longer available.

Comment: Here: http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=This+is+pretty+fun+too.+Do+something+for+your+group+tag

Answer (score 3):

Basically the question is: can you post a formatted text on the wall? The answer is no, sorry. Facebook currently doesn't support any html, markdown-like syntax, or html entities in their wall posts, only plain text.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following html tags (they may get filtered, but may not)

```
<pre> my code </pre>

<tt> my code </tt>
```

Comment: They are escaped unfortunately.

Comment: bummer, the only other thing I can think of is to use a service like gist.github.com or pastie.org and some of those urls give a preview in facebook, aka the youtube thumbnail preview.

Answer (score 0):

I get that this is a 9 year old question, but I was looking for something similar, saw http://qaz.wtf/u/ in the comments, and went digging. 
Found this:
https://github.com/cpsdqs/monotext 
It's a single-file script (js) that appears to accomplish the same thing:
  
  
I'd imagine you could (as I plan to) use it as a base to convert something faster than one line at a time. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

monospace: Try a backtick ``before and after your text.`

italic: `_`*italic*`_`

bold: `*`*bold*`*`